# How to get rid of cursor highlight?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, settings, accessibility, cursor

I held down some key for too long while I was thinking and the Mac bleeped at me to intimate that some mode had been triggered, analogous to StickyKeys or FilterKeys on Windows.

Now, whenever I click, a yellow circle appears around my cursor - some sort of accessibility feature to show where my cursor is on the screen, I assume.

I've looked all over through the accessibility and trackpad settings but can't find how to toggle it off again.

How can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out this is from the Loom app. Quitting the app disabled it.